# how to call another method in C# in another class

Tags: c#

1. I want to use C# develop autocad and I build a new windows form project and add a button on it, I will put the parameter in the form.
2. The question is: I want to write code below the click button to call the method in another class

   ```
   private void guocheng1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       MyCommands myMyCommands = new MyCommands();

       MyCommands.Myds = new Myds() ;
   }


   public void Myds() // This method can have any name
   {
       // Put your command code here
       Document doc = Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument;
       Database db = doc.Database;
       Editor ed = doc.Editor;
       ed.WriteMessage("\r\nThis   is  an  Initialization  Startup text.");   
   }
   ```

I don't know what's wrong.

Comment: It looks like you should just be using `myMyCommands.Myds();`. You're not trying to construct anything at that point, right?

Answer (score 1):

```
 private void guocheng1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MyCommands myMyCommands = new MyCommands();

        myMyCommands.Myds() ; //this, its not a static method. Also, this is how you call a method. 
     }

public void Myds() // This method can have any name
{
    // Put your command code here
    Document doc = Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument;
    Database db = doc.Database;
    Editor ed = doc.Editor;
    ed.WriteMessage("\r\nThis   is  an  Initialization  Startup text.");

}
```